# Array printing with for-loop and .setText() method?

Tags: android

I am using this to try to display all the characters in the array but all it prints is "g"
I tested the same code using System.out.println() in regular java and it works fine

```
        String testarray[]={"a","s","d","f","g"};

    for(int l=0; l<testarray.length; l++){
        String temp="";
        temp=temp+testarray[l];
        display.setText(""+temp);
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: While Samuel probably deserves to be the answer to your question (I voted it up), in my opinion (being fair), please take a moment to read my answer, as I believe it will clear things for you. You'll understand much better, I promise. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your code, I will avoid what others are saying and I'll explain to you in simple laymen terms:

**In plain english, there is a difference between *set* and *print*.**

When you *set* something, you replace whatever was there with a new value. When you *print*, you *append* something to whatever was there. `System.out.print` thus appends stuff, while `setText` sets stuff instead.

The `for` happens so fast (computer can compute gazillion stuffs faster than you can blink) that you see a bunch of `setText` stuff in succession, and end up with only "g". That's why you need, as others said, to "append" stuff.

However, simpler than what others have said, there is only one line that you need inside this whole for loop.

```
display.setText(display.getText() + testarray[l]);
```

**And that is all you need.**

Comment: tyvm! this explained it well!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this, is with a for-each loop.

Try:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView);
String testarray[] = {"a","s","d","f","g"};

String print = "";
  for(String s : testarray) {
    print += s;
  }

tv.setText(print)
```

This will print out asdfg

The problem in your code is you initialize the variable WITHIN the for loop, meaning for each time it goes through, it remakes the String = "", to fix this initialize it like I do in my example. Also, don't set the textview until after the loop.

If you're not familiar with the for-each loop, its basically:

```
for each ( object x in objectArray)
  do this
```

EDIT:

System.out.println() != .setText()

.setText() SETS the text of the view, every time you reset the text, you do exactly that, remove the old text, and add the new

Comment: This is basically the same as the other answer...but my question remains...why does one have to put the tv.setText() method outside the loop? Does it not update everytime the loop is looped or does it not work that way in Android?

Comment: @user947659 when you setText() it sets the text of the textview, which keeps getting reset, it only can hold one value at a time, textview is not the same as System.out.println()

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong way.You are initializing the temp string with empty string in for loop.
So every time it will be assign empty string and then you are concating the string from array so temp string will have only String which you are assigning from array and then you are displaying on textview.

This way you can set all the character by creating string on Textview

```
String testarray[]={"a","s","d","f","g"};
String temp="";

for(int l=0; l<testarray.length; l++){
   temp=temp+testarray[l];
}

display.setText(temp);
```

Comment: No it is not android or any other programming issue actually it is your code is not properly organized.

Comment: You are setting the text in loop so that every time the textview has new string and old will be removed.